# How can a assign a higher and equal clause to a function, without getting true or false results? IN R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x))

fun.1 <- function(x) 1000*x+3000*y

fun.1 >=300000*  **#this clause gives me error; if instead y run:strong text*

                                     *fun.1 <- function(x) 1000*x+3000*y )>=300000,* 

                                     **then I get true or false*

p + stat_function(fun = fun.1) + xlim(0,300)
```

Comment: I do not follow. Are in you interested in ```ifelse```? For example ```ifelse(1:5 > 2, -(1:5), 1:5)```

Comment: I want to plot a line with the function 1000x+3000y; but 1000x+3000y has to be higher or equal to 300000

Answer (score 0):

The first part recommendation is to change your function to:

```r
y = function(x) 1000 / 3000 * x
```

This function is easy to solve and simplifies our logic. Since this is simple, we can also solve for when this function is above 300,000 with basic math.

```r
thresh = 300000
x_min = thresh / (1000 / 3000)
x_min
## [1] 9e+05
```

Then last, we can change the plot call to use the `x_min` as part of the `xlim`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x))

p + stat_function(fun = y) + xlim(x_min,x_min + 300)
```

[image]